# error in migrating laravel file to xampp server

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5.4

i am trying to migrate a file in laravel 5. i have already created a users table and successfully migrated it, but i get this error

> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users'
>   alre  ady exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not
>   null auto_incr  ement primary key, `name` varchar(191) not null,
>   `email` varchar(191) not n  ull, `password` varchar(191) not null,
>   `remember_token` varchar(100) null,  `created_at` timestamp null,
>   `updated_at` timestamp null) default character   set utf8mb4 collate
>   utf8mb4_unicode_ci)

database\migrations\2018_01_22_091142_create_authors_table.php(file i am trying to migrate.
database\migrations\2018_01_20_085218_create_users_table.php(file already migrated)
thanks in advance

Comment: the error is self-explanatory , you are trying to create an already created table

Comment: php artisan migrate:reset  .run this before php artisan migrate

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory , you are trying to create an already created table.

you need to drop your table, in your Down method drop your table.

**ONLY WHEN YOU ARE WRITING A MIGRATION TO CREATE NEW TABLES**

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
```

also you can check for tables existence using `hasTable` method, to prevent creating the already created tables

```
if (!Schema::hasTable('users'))
{
    // create the new table
}
```